# Git Shell. Permission denied when trying to git clone

Tags: git, shell, vim

I am using windows 10. I installed Git and I tried to git clone a vim plugin in `C:\Programs Files (x86)\Vim\Vimfiles\Bundle` and I get

> fatal: could not create work tree dir 'nerdtree': Permission denied

I suppose it's because I have to have admin rights to modify files in `C:\Programs Files (x86)`, but when I right click on Git Shell and click "Run as Administrator" it doesn't open the shell and now I don't know what to do.

Comment: You should be able to run "git clone" in the command prompt?

Comment: Don't clone into an applications installation directory. That's a bad idea. Clone somewhere you control and load the plugin in your user `.vimrc`, etc.

Comment: Could you please paste the exact command you are trying to run? Furthermore please make sure to clone in a dir where you got write permissions on.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\bundle> git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git`

I'm using Pathogen to easy install plugins for vim and in the guides it's sayed to git clone in the bundle folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cloning the project in your home directory. Also you can set the a path variable to the git bin library so you can run git commands from the standard command line.

Comment: He mentioned it is Windows 10, not Linux. As far as I understand there is no "home" directory in Windows.

Comment: Of course there is a "home" directory on Windows, it's the one that has got you username on it… like on every OS.

Comment: I am not gonna start a fight but it's not called "home" its called "user" on windows.

Comment: Its still your home directory. Two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Well I am using "Pathogen" so I can easilly install vim plugins. And in the guides it is said to git clone a particular plug in the bundle folder which is vin, which is in C:\Programs Files (x86). And I need write permission.


I guess I can download rar file and extract there, but I want to figure out a way to git clone in the folder.